# React / Typescript: "Property 'children' is missing in type" in imported library

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Pulling a lib from NPM into a Create React App project..

```
import {UseWalletProvider} from 'use-wallet'

..........

<UseWalletProvider chainId={chainId} connectors={connectors}>
  <div>....</div>
</UseWalletProvider>
```

Getting a:

```
Property 'children' is missing in type '{ chainId: number; connectors: {}; }' but required in type 'UseWalletProviderProps'.
```

I didn't write the `use-wallet`, I'm just importing it and using it.

How can the mentioned error be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define children props type since you use children.

Try to add:

```
type UseWalletProviderProps = {
  chainId: number;
  connectors: {};
  children: React.ReactNode;
}
```

Comment: A `UseWalletProviderProps` type is included in the `index.d.ts` that comes with `use-wallet` npm library. React is just not picking it up.